# Retrieve already sold products

Tags: magento2, product, product-list

I need to create a list of product which has been placed to an order with status complete, is there a way to get a collection of this product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
protected $order;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $order
)
{
    $this->order = $order;
}

...
...

$orders = $this->order->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status','complete');

$products = array();
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
        $products[] = $item->getProductId();
    }
}

$product_list = array_unique($products);
print_r($product_list);
```

Comment: is there any chance to use like join left to reduce the use of foreach?

Comment: addFieldToFilter function will automatically reduce the SQL query.